# No-argument constructor calling 2-argument constructor

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I am trying to call to make a 2-arg constructor the default constructor.
By this I mean; when the no-arg constructor is called, it calls the
2-arg constructor with default values.

```
public class Foo
{
  int foo1;
  int foo2;

  public Foo()
  {
    Foo(0, 0); //error          //I also tried this.Foo(0,0);
  }
  public Foo(int one, int two)
  {
    this.foo1 = one;
    this.foo2 = two;
  }
}
```

How do I call the 2nd constructor?

Comment: This is *almost* a great question ( if it had included the specific question "How do I call the 2nd constructor?" ;) but it lacks the part where you describe (and by that I mean copy/paste) the error output that happened trying it either way.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Just write

```
public Foo()
{
    this(0, 0);
}
```

Note that it has to be the very first thing in the constructor.

(This is specified in [§8.8.7.1 "Explicit Constructor Invocations" of *The Java Language Specification, Java SE 8 Edition*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.7.1), which also specifies how to invoke a specific superclass constructor.)